# Pyspark Schema for Json file

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a complex json file into a spark dataframe . Spark recognizes the schema but mistakes a field as string which happens to be an empty array. (Not sure why it is String type when it has to be an array type)
Below is a sample that i am expecting

```
arrayfield:[{"name":"somename"},{"address" : "someadress"}]
```

Right now the data is as below

```
arrayfield:[]
```

what this does to my code is that when ever i try querying arrayfield.name it fails. I know i can input a schema while reading the file but since the json structure is really complex writing it from scratch doesn't really work out. I tried getting the schema using df.schema(which displays in StructType) and modifying it as per my requirement but how do i pass back a string into a StructType ? This might be really silly but i am finding it hard to fix this. Are there any tool  / utility which would help me generate the strutType

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass StructType object to DF constructor.

Let's say Your DF with mistakes after executing

```
df.schema
```

prints output like this:

```
StructType(List(StructField(data1,StringType,true),StructField(data2,StringType,true)))
```

so, You need need translate this string into executable script.

1. Add an import for types

   ```
   from pyspark.sql.types import *
   ```
2. Change List and parentheses to python's brackets

   ```
   List() -> []
   ```
3. After each type declaration add parentheses

   ```
   StringType -> StringType()
   ```
4. Fix boolean values strings

   ```
   true -> True
   ```
5. Assign it to variable

   ```
   schema = StructType([
           StructField("data1", StringType(),True),
           StructField("data2", StringType(),True)])
   ```
6. Create new DF object

   ```
   spark.read.csv(path, schema=schema)
   ```

And You are done.