# pyspark input read schema for array and struct to read json

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load some json file to pyspark with only specific columns like below

```
df = spark.read.json("sample/json/", schema=schema)
```

So I started writing a input read schema for below main schema

```
 |-- test_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test_file: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test_url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test_ids: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ct: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dimmingSetting: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- hue: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- modeId: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried to write for the direct string type but I am not able to write for array and struct type

```
 schema = StructType([
    StructField('test_name', StringType()),
     StructField('test_file', StringType()),
     StructField('test_id', StringType()),
     StructField('test_type', StringType()),
     StructField('test_url', StringType()),
 ])
```

How to extend this schema for

```
|-- test_ids: array (nullable = true)
|-- value: struct (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the extended version should be

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, ArrayType, LongType, DoubleType
schema = StructType([
    StructField('test_name', StringType(), True),
    StructField('test_file', StringType(), True),
    StructField('test_id', StringType(), True),
    StructField('test_type', StringType(), True),
    StructField('test_url', StringType(), True),
    StructField('test_ids', ArrayType(StringType(), True), True),
    StructField('value', StructType([
        StructField('ct', LongType(), True),
        StructField('dimmingSetting', LongType(), True),
        StructField('hue', DoubleType(), True),
        StructField('modeId', StringType(), True)
        ])
    )
])
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: How to generate such a code structure from json specs?

Comment: Found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44585520/pyspark-schema-for-json-file?rq=1